# using a custom stemmer how can I mark positions (outside of solr)

Tags: solr

[KeywordRepeat](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/language-analysis.html#keywordrepeatfilterfactory)

> Emits each token twice, one with the KEYWORD attribute and once without. If placed before a stemmer, the result will be that you will get the unstemmed token preserved on the same position as the stemmed one.

I am using a custom stemmer outside of solr. I want to emulate this feature. I can duplicate the tokens myself, but I need to mark the unstemmed token as having the same position (PositionIncrementAttribute). Can this be done outside of from solr? Or is a java tokenizer within solr required? Thanks!